# Pass missing argument to function using do.call

Tags: r

How do I pass a missing argument to a function using `do.call`? The following does not work:

```
x <- array(1:9, c(3, 3))
do.call(`[`, list(x, , 1))
```

I expect this to do the same calculation as

```
x[,1]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `quote(expr=)`

```r
x <- array(1:9, c(3, 3))

do.call(`[`, list(x, quote(expr=), 1))
#> [1] 1 2 3

identical(x[,1], do.call(`[`, list(x, quote(expr=), 1)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`` do.call(`[`, alist(x,, 1)) `` also works.

So does `` do.call(`[`, list(x, TRUE, 1)) `` for this specific case, since subsetting rows with `TRUE` keeps all of them.

Comment: that was quick, thanks!

Comment: Why does `quote(expr=)` work while `quote()` won't? Quite a hack! :)

Comment: I guess it's a nuance between providing "nothing" and not providing anything :). If the syntax irks you you can call `substitute()` without args too.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Thanks to @moodymudskipper: ("`is_missing()` is always `TRUE` so you're just subsetting rows and keeping everything. We could do `do.call([, list(x, TRUE, 1))`. This solves this specific issue (perhaps better in fact), but not the general one of dealing with missing arguments.")

I meant `rlang`s `missing_arg()`:

```
do.call(`[`, list(x, rlang::missing_arg() , 1))
```

**First answer:** not good -> see comments moodymudskipper:

We could use `rlang`s `is_missing()`:
See here https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/missing_arg.html

"rlang::is_missing() simplifies these rules by never treating default arguments as missing, even in internal contexts:"

```
do.call(`[`, list(x, rlang::is_missing() , 1))
```

Comment: Did you mean `rlang::missing_arg()`?

Comment: Yes thank you, but `is_missing()` works here also. ? But I think the correct one is `missing_arg()`?

Comment: `is_missing()` is always `TRUE` so you're just subsetting rows and keeping everything. We could do `do.call(`[`, list(x, TRUE, 1))`. This solves this specific issue (perhaps better in fact), but not the general one of dealing with missing arguments.